# What is difference between Traffic manager(classic) and Traffic manager in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

What is difference between **Traffic manager(classic)** and **Traffic manager** in Azure?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, it is the one service, it is using different dev models. There are two development models in Azure called Azure Service Management (classic) and Azure Resource Management. The ARM is the new one, which is the one you mentioned as a second.

It is recommended to use the new one, but it does not have yet the full functional parity with the classic one. [More about that](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-powershell-arm/), chapter "Comparison with the Azure Traffic Manager Service Management API".

Comment: Slight clarification, Azure Resource Management is the new version.

Comment: Sorry, my English... :(  changing the answer. Thank you